# How to store a Vector3 list in a string Unity c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, unity-game-engine

I do not really know how I would start to program this, the reason why I want to use a string system rather than a list system is because a list system takes up too much ram on my pc, lagging the overall game. (I have 16 gb ram)

This is how I would like it too work: say I have a string labeled "1\n", "2\n", "3\n", "4\n", "5\n", "6\n" then if the index of the string I wanted to get was = 0. I would get a vector3 = 1, 2, 3
and if the index was 1 it would be 4, 5,6.

If you know any other ways of going about this problem, it would be highly appreciated.

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Container : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Bchanged;

    void GetBlockbyIndex(int index)
    {
        //Get what block it is based on its index 
        /*Example:
         * index = 0;
         * Bchanged = "1\n", "2\n", "3\n", "4\n", "5\n", "6\n";
         * Vector3 answer = new vector3(1, 2, 3);
         */
        Vector3 anwser = Bchanged[index];
    }
    void AddBlock(Vector3 block)
    {
        //Add block to string list
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing that a list lags? There's not really a great way to do this. Storing data in a string you'd still need to split it on a delimiter, pack it in a more standard format like JSON or pad everything to have consistent length between indexes. Accessing and using a substring is much slower than just accessing a vector in a list. Accessing a list is O(1) by index. And if order doesn't matter, you can swap delete for O(1) and add for O(1).

Comment: A big reason it needs to be saved a string is for in the future I would like it to be networked, and networking strings is far easier than networking list to sync up. Also I would like to use player prefs to save the data.

Comment: Then use JSON. No reason to reinvent the wheel. At runtime use a list of vec3 then just serialize in when needed. You can also send vec3 over a network.

Comment: My guy this easier based on how the rest of my games code works I found the answer from Strom.

Comment: If that's true then good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding the data in a string will use more ram than the Vector3.
A Char is 16 bits. 16 * (3 for single digit + 2 delimiters) = 80 bits.
A Vector3 is 3 floats = 96 bits, and can store more than 0-9.

Lists add a little overhead above an array, but gives you the ability to dynamically add space.

If you know how many items will be added use the initial capacity parameter:

`List<Vector3> Blocks = new List<Vector3>(100);`
This will prevent the resizing reallocation of the underlying array.

---

You can save one third of the space if your values are all positive integers and the range of X,Y,Z  = (0,0,0) - (2047,2047,1023)

You can store the Vector3 in a packed unsigned integer (32bits).

```
List<UInt32> Blocks = new List<UInt32>(); // insert max count if known

const int SCALE = 1; 
// for Grid alignment(16 makes the stored values 1, 2,... 2047 -> 16, 32,... 32752)

Vector3 GetBlockbyIndex(int index)
    {
        //Get what block it is based on its index 
        
        return new Vector3(Blocks[index] & 0x7FF, 
                          (Blocks[index] & 0x3FFFFF) >> 11, 
                          Blocks[index] >>22) * SCALE;
    }
    void AddBlock(Vector3 block)
    {
        //Add block to list
        // Watch the input range, (2048,0,0) becomes (0,1,0)
        block /= SCALE;
        Blocks.Add((uint)block.X | (uint)block.Y << 11 | (uint)block.Z << 22);
    }
```